# Updating From PHP 7.3 to PHP 7.4 Throws Fatal Error and Won't Load WordPress Site

Tags: php

When updating a Wordpress site's PHP to 7.4, it crashes the site to a blank, white screen - and throws this fatal error:

**Fatal error: Unparenthesized 'a ? b : c ? d : e' is not supported. Use either '(a ? b : c) ? d : e' or 'a ? b : (c ? d : e)'**

This is the section of code the error references:

```
// check if image is in the hidden fields list
                if (!in_array('image', $search_parameters['results_hide_fields']))
                {
                    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail');
                    $extra_class = $image ? "with_image" : "";
                    $post_type = $image ? "" : get_post_format($post->ID) != "" ? get_post_format($post->ID) : "standard";
                    $iconfont = $image ? "" : av_icon_string($post_type);

                }
```

This is the specific line of code the error references:

```
$post_type = $image ? "" : get_post_format($post->ID) != "" ? get_post_format($post->ID) : "standard";
```

Thank you for any suggestions or insights!

Comment: What's the problem? Add the appropriate parentheses like it says.

Comment: Is this your code or internal to WordPress?

Comment: So you upgraded your PHP without upgrading the Wordpress/plugins first? Not the smartest thing to do. Like upgrading a USB cable from B to C without checking if your device can support it.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Also, you'll find lots of questions concerning that error here (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unparenthesized+%27a+%3F+b+%3A+c+%3F+d+%3A+e%27+is+not+supported) and notes in the changelog. Please do a bit of research up front! As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you. New here, and not at all familiar with PHP code (more front end guy). Just looking for a little guidance. Did research those articles on SO, but nothing seemed helpful to this particular line of code. Thanks for the links!

Comment: @emix No. The plugins were updated prior. This error is regarding the theme (also updated ).

Comment: @Barmar Was looking for a bit of guidance as to where I can try placing the parenthesis? PHP is new to me. Thanks. I could have stated that more clearly.

Comment: Check the precedence rules and add parentheses that match them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested ternary expressions are deprecated since PHP 7.4 so you should try chancing the failing code line to:

```
$post_type = $image ? "" : (get_post_format($post->ID) != "" ? get_post_format($post->ID) : "standard");
```

Comment: Thank you @juri I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked! Thank you!